# Issues adding second context to solution

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have multiple projects in my solution. What I am trying to do is get each plugin to have its own context.

When calling `Enable-Migrations` on the second project (making sure the drop down has my project selected), I get `No context type was found in the assembly 'Plugin.Test'.`. I do have a class in this project deriving from `DbContext` so am a little unsure as to what it wants.

This is the context in my second project:

```
public class SecondContext : DbContext, IDbContext
```

Could someone shed some light on how it's looking for a context so that I can make the changes to my second projects so it can be found?

p.s My first project EF integration is fine, this is purely when trying to add another context.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the context name:

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ContextTypeName
NamespaceOfContext.ContextA -ProjectName ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne
-StartupProjectName NameOfMainProject  -ConnectionStringName ContextA
```

For example:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName SecondContext
```

Comment: I tried this and got a message about the context not existing (I can't recall the message exactly but it's one of the first things I tried).